# PHP generated JavaScript onClick, with PHP array, quotes problem

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, dom-events

```
echo '<a onClick="articleDeleteConfirm("'.
      $row["title_$lang"].'","'.$_GET["editPage"]).'">';
```

The main problem is with: `$row["title_$lang"]`, I have to use `$lang` variable inside. `"` and `'` just not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you describe actually has nothing to do with your PHP variables, those are all being output as expected. The problem is that you need to escape the `"` inside of the `<a>` and you've misplaced a `)`.

Your original would output:

```
<a onClick="articleDeleteConfirm("value1","value2">
```

That is not valid HTML (even the highlighter dislikes it). Now, notice the `\`'s in the following (and that the paren was moved into the string).

```
echo '<a onClick="articleDeleteConfirm(\''
     .$row["title_".$lang."].'\',\''.$_GET["editPage"].'\')">';
```

The escaped version outputs:

```
<a onClick="articleDeleteConfirm('value1','value2')">
```

It uses single quotes inside of double quotes to provide easy to read (and valid) html. Now, you have another issue with your code.

Any time you output a `$_REQUEST` variable to the browser, you risk something called [cross-site-scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Someone could put JavaScript into `$_GET["editPage"]` and it would smell bad. The easy way to avoid it? Use [`htmlentities($_GET["editPage"])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: Yeah, i used this, and printf,
printf('<a onClick="articleDeleteConfirm(\'%s\',\'%s\')">', $row["title_$lang"], $_GET["editPage"])

Should I use htmlentities with every GET ?

Comment: @appl3r only if they are supposed to go to the user.

Comment: @appl3r If it is supposed to go to the DB, use the appropriate escape string syntax.

Comment: Maybe my problem not totally solved,
the final code is this:
      $delete = printf('<a onClick="articleDeleteConfirm(\'%s\',\'%s\')">', $row["title_$lang"], htmlentities($_GET["editPage"]));
      $delete .= '<img src="images/delete-icon.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Törlés" /></a>';
      echo $delete;

but its prints numbers before the image, 52-52-50...

Comment: You mean `sprintf`, that will return the pre-formatted string. `printf` outputs the string and returns the number of characters in the string. You don't want that

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem too, I don't know exactly why but I had syntax error no matter what I did, So I tried this and got answer.

The problem is that you're using a double quotation to open onClick and again you're using another double quotation to open an string.

Use this and you'll get answer.

```
echo '<a onClick="articleDeleteConfirm('.char(39).$row["title_$lang"].char(39).','.char(39).$_GET["editPage"]).char(39).'>';
```